# maya export fbx and import it in another maya, all materials cannot be imported

Tags: maya

I'm sure exported fbx has inner material, fbx correctly show materials in unity model preview, but when i import fbx in another maya scene, model is grey
[image]

Comment: during import is Maya alerting you to missing textures or prompting for repathing?

Comment: @GerardFalla no, not any message

Comment: @GerardFalla is this the kind of questions you were hoping to attract?

Comment: By which you mean the "turn the relevant toggle on" kind of question or the "turn the relevant toggle on in your **3D app**" kind of question? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I fix it, in new scene, I should enable textured[image]